# New accounts daily at WP Multi-User site under development, Analytics reports no traffic. What gives?

Tags: buddypress, spam, google-analytics

I'm working on a Wordpress Multi-user site (Buddypress?). Every day, there are between 5-15 new accounts created, yet Google Analytics is reporting little-to-no traffic.

The site is far from finished, and I long ago disabled all content-creation features for non-administrators (because as soon as it went live people or bots started creating spam pages).

My question is, how are there new accounts if there are no new visitors? Are these bot accounts and that's why Google Analytics is not reporting them as visitors? I'm perplexed by the whole situation as this is my first attempt at a community site and I don't understand how there are so many new accounts, how people (if they're even people) are finding out about this site that I haven't advertised or promoted at all being in that it's far from finished, and add in the fact that according to Google Analytics there are no new visitors (or less visitors than new accounts created on some days).

Sorry for the run-on sentence but if anyone can help explain to me what is going on with this and what the motive is for whoever or whatever is creating these new accounts I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will someone who knows the answer to this please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I kindly and respectfully ask the community to take 30 seconds out of your day and please explain this phenomenon to me.

I get that it's cool to either ignore or ridicule those who are not savvy with this sort of stuff, but I need to know how this is happening, who's behind it and what they want.

I don't know where else to go to find an answer from people who know so much more than I do about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The site now has almost 900 accounts created. Google analytics is showing 83 total visitors in the site's entire history.

How can there be 900 different accounts if only 83 people have visited the site?